# Function as parameter in Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to put a function into a parameter for Jquery Ajax like below. dataType and data are given as functions. dataType returns a value of JSON if the returntype is JSON and text if isJson is false.

dataVal and dataVar are arrays containing the parameter names and values used to construct the data paramater. The result of the data: function would be a string as:

```
{dataVar[0]:dataVal[0],dataVar[1]:dataVal[1],.....,}
```

I'm getting an error when I try this, so, just wanted to know if this method was possible.

```
function getAjaxResponse(page, isJson, dataVar, dataVal, dfd) {
    $.ajax(page, {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: function () {
            if (isJson == true) {
                return "JSON";
            } else {
                return "text";
            }
        },
        data: function () {
            var dataString = '{';
            for (var i = 0; i < dataVar.length; i++) {
                dataString = dataString + dataVar[i] + ':' + dataVal[i] + ',';
            }
            console.log(dataString);
            return dataString + '}';
        },
        success: function (res) {
            dfd.resolve(res);
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit**

As per answers and comments, made the changes. The updated function is as below. This works:

```
function getAjaxResponse(page, isJson, dataVar, dataVal, dfd) {
    $.ajax(page, {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: isJson ? "JSON" : "text",
        data: function () {
            var dataString ="";
            for (var i = 0; i < dataVar.length; i++) {
                if (i == dataVar.length - 1) {
                    dataString = dataString + dataVar[i] + '=' + dataVal[i];
                } else {
                    dataString = dataString + dataVar[i] + '=' + dataVal[i] + ',';
                }
            }
            return dataString;
        }(),
        success: function (res) {
            dfd.resolve(res);
        }
    });
}
```

And my original question is answered. But apparently, data is not getting accepted.

The return value of the data function is just treated as the parameter name and jquery just adds a : to the end of the request like so:

```
{dataVar[0]:dataVal[0]}:
```

So, my server is unable to pick up on the proper paramater name.

Comment: I don't think so, you'd have to set data and dataType as the result of the execution of these functions

Comment: WTH don't you use `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Just put `dataType: isJson ? "JSON" : "text",`…

Comment: @Bergi: The code works now, as per answers but the 'data' result is not accepted. Apparently the return value is just treated as the parameter name. The sent data is like so: {TableName:tblLGRQueryTracking}:

Comment: Not accepted by what? Is the data invalid or the format? `{TableName:tblLGRQueryTracking}` is no valid JSON at least

Comment: I think, my Jquery takes the result of the function which supplies the data parameter as just the parameter name and not as the entire query string. Hence a semicolon at the end.

Comment: @Bergi: Also, the chrome network inspector shows the {dataVar[0]:dataVal[0]} as bold. usually the parameter names are bold and the data values are in normal font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the manual](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> data
>   Type: PlainObject or String

So no.

Call the function. Use the return value.

```
data: function () { ... }();
//                       ^^ call the function
```

Comment: Original question answered. Thank You..:-)

Answer (score 2):

Not that way. But it will work with a little change:

```
(function () {
    if (isJson == true) {
        return "JSON";
    } else {
        return "text";
    }
})()
```

That should work. You just call the function immidiately after you created it. This way, dataType is a String and the script will work.
Same with data. Also use the `(function(){})()`-notation here

Comment: There's no need to wrap the whole thing in parenthesis, it's inside an object literal so it is already in a context that will make it a function expression instead of a function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

> jquery just adds a : to the end of the request like so:
>
> ```
> {dataVar[0]:dataVal[0]}:
> ```

No, your devtools display does. However, as you're data string does not contain a `=` sign, and you send the content as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the whole body is interpreted as if it was a parameter name.

For sending JSON, you should:

- use `contentType: "application/json"`
- use `data: JSON.stringify(_.object(dataVar, dataVal))`<sup>1</sup>

to ensure valid JSON is sent with the correct header (and correctly recognised as such at the server).

<sub>1: `_.object` is the [`object` function from Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#object) which does exactly what you want, but you can use an [IEFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) as well:

`JSON.stringify(function(p,v){var d={};for(var i=0;i<p.length;i++)d[p[i]]=v[i];return d;}(dataVar, dataVal))`</sub>

Comment: What if I just wanted to send data as data: { dataVar[0]: dataVal[0] } as I've been successfully doing for a long time and not as JSON content.

Comment: Do as you want if it works, but a) don't call it "JSON" b) don't expect your server to parse it correctly c) don't expect devtools to display the request properly

Comment: Thanks, the JSON.stringify method works wonders. And I took your hint and tried adding an equals instead of a semicolon and the server side program seems to accept it. Fragile, yet working. Thanks for all your help...:-)

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the function with parenthesis like below:

```
function func1(){
//func1 code in here
}
function func2(func1){
//func2 code in here
//call func1 like this:
func1();
}
```

So, you can use like this:

```
data: function () {
//your stuff her
}(); // which mean you are having data()
```