# jQuery ajax request data not send

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying some idea on a ajax send,but i can't find why this code can't not send any parameter to jsp and thorw the nullpointerException.

I fix my code here,thanks for reponse.

```
var dfd = {
        resolve : function (res) {
             $("#Div123").html(res);
        }
    };

function getAjaxResponse(page, responseType, dataVar, dataVal, dfd) {
    var dataObject = $.parseJSON('{"'+ dataVar +'":"'+ dataVal +'"}');
    $.ajax(page, {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: responseType,
        data: dataObject,
        success: function (responseData) {
            dfd.resolve(responseData);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        getAjaxResponse("ajaxreponse.jsp", "text", "aa", "yes", dfd);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: The dataType and data options does not accept a function

Comment: You have to call the function and using the return value: use function(){  }() instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function as parameter in Jquery Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076318/function-as-parameter-in-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `data` to:

```
data: { dataVar : dataVal }
```

and your `dataType` to

```
dataType: isJSON ? "JSON" : "text
```

They both don't accept functions.

`data` accepts plain object or string and `dataType` accepts only string

Comment: Thanks Amit Joki,you fix my problem.